# Looking to represent a fraction template in HTML/JS with input field

Tags: javascript, html, syntax

I have an input field (type text) and a button that generates a general fraction template. Right now it looks similar to this (X/Y). I have been trying to make this look nicer by using .sup() and .sub() methods, but unfortunately I have had no success in getting the final form to look as follows:

(<sup>X</sup>/<sub>Y</sub>)

any tips to help make this more aesthetically pleasing?

Comment: show us an example. Make a jsFiddle

Comment: Those methods have been deprecated.

Comment: @philtune Why jsFiddle and not a SO snippet?

Comment: @Madbreaks either/or... could be a CodePen, whichever

Comment: @philtune Point: why suggest an external website? I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: I see people referencing either jsFiddle or Codepen most often on this site. Possibly because SO snippets came about relatively recently. No real preference.

Comment: Explain? I basically just set the text in the input field to "(Y/Z)" but I would like it to look more like a fraction opposed to just like integer operations.

Answer (score 1):

You say in your question you want to format the text inside a `<input>` field. This is not possible, exactly: the contents of an `<input>` are plain text and can only have a single uniform style. Here are some alternatives:

- **Simple:** Use two `<input>`s:

  ```
  <p>(<sup><input></sup>/<sub><input></sub>)</p>
  ```

  This will always require the user to tab between the two fields rather than typing a slash, unless you add code to adjust it (which is very error-prone).
- **Advanced:** Use `contenteditable` to allow the user to edit a region including `<sup>` and `<sub>` elements. This requires additional code to extract the results and deal with the user e.g. deleting the subscripted text, because you're basically allowing the user to edit the HTML in this area (and they can do wacky things like pasting in styled text/HTML from elsewhere).

  ```
  <p>(<span contenteditable><sup>a</sup>/<sub>b</sub></span>)</p>
  ```
- **Wacky:** Use superscripted/subscripted characters:

  ```
  <p>(<input value="ⁿ/ₓ">)</p>
  ```

  The problem with this method is that there are very few letters available like this, though there are digits; e.g. ¹²/₃₄.
- **Probably won't work:** Use the fraction slash character, U+2044 “⁄”, in the division template.

  ```
  <input value="1&#x2044;2">
  ```

  Depending on the OS, browser, font, and characters present in the template, using this character *may* cause the numbers to the left and right to be arranged diagonally or vertically as a fraction. Here's some samples to see if it works for you: 1⁄2 1⁄3 3⁄4.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize I was unable to alter the appearance of the text. Does this include colors as well? @kevin Reid

Comment: Also what about changing the font size of certain text elements

Comment: Yes, you cannot style any part of the text separately, at all. It will all appear in the style set for the `<input>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something simple like ...

```
(<span class="numer">X</span>/<span class="denom">Y</span>)
```

Then, in CSS ...

```
.numer {
  position: relative;
  top: -0.5em;
  left: 0.2em;
}
.denom {
  position: relative;
  top: 0.5em;
  left: -0.2em;
}
```

You might have to make some adjustments for the parens ...

PS. I didn't test these values, might also need some adjustment.

**UPDATE 1**:

See **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/45tx5s9e/)**

**UPDATE 2**:

Assuming jQuery here ...

```
function frac_display(ob, x, y) {
  $(ob).html([
    "(<span class='numer'>",
    x,
    "</span>",
    "/",
    "<span class='denom'>",
    y,
    "</span>)"
  ].join("");
}
```

This function will take a unique element identifier (class or id identifier as `.fraction1` or `#frac_234`), an x and y value and places the code inside the element.

Comment: I want this template to appear every time I hit a button, so essentially I could have multiple buttons. Can I connect this to a js function so it generates a new template each time?

Comment: I don't see why not ... let me see what I can put together.

Comment: I thought you wanted the fraction displayed in an `<input>`, no?

Comment: My understanding was that the input provides the data to generate the template (resulting display) above.